# How do I escape a certain word in a URL with Google Analytics regex?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a regex to escape a certain word in a URL with Google Analytics goals.

Currently the URL path is:

1. /pricing/mls
2. /pricing/armls
3. /pricing/armls/bundle/5

Step 1 is static, and will always stay that way but step 2 has over 80 different possibilities. I wanted to set up a Regex that will specifically escape "mls". Using the `(.*)` would also grab the mls page which I'm trying to escape. Currently my regex looks like this:

`^\/pricing\/mls$`

`^\/pricing\/(.*)` **this is where I'm trying to escape the mls portion**
`^\/pricing\/(.*)\/bundle\/(5|6|7)`

I tried `(?!mls)` but Google Analytics doesn't support negative look aheads. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks everyone!

Comment: Are all the `/(.*)` variations different takes on `mls` (like `armls`). Also, im kinda floored that GA doesn't support neg. lookaheads :-(

Comment: For the most part yes. It could be `crmls, armls, tmls, mlspin, etc.` Sometimes they're words like `realcomp` hence why the (.*) to just grab everything. And yes, it's a little infuriating that GA doesn't do negative look aheads!

Answer (score 1):

Without a negative lookaround is going to get messy.

The only clean way I see is to use an optimized whitelist of alternations like this:

```
^\/pricing\/((?:[ac]r|t)mls|mlspin|realcomp)\/bundle\/(5|6|7)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YTnqWY/1)

Tip: I used [myregextester.com](https://myregextester.com/index.php) to get the inner part optimized (just enter your pattern, tick the OPTIMIZE checkbox, and submit).

<sub>[*]: Side note: Google Analytics doesn't support single and multiline modes since URLs can't contain newlines. So, there should be never any need for `^` and `$` to match anywhere but the beginning and end of the whole string.</sub>